# Recursively following link and running grep on any pages

Tags: bash, grep, curl

I'm trying to grep through some logs at the url below to look for a specific username. However I'm getting no results, it just runs without stopping.

```
grepfor="username"
urls=("https://tgstation13.org/parsed-logs/terry/data/logs/2019/01")
while [ ${#urls[@]} -ne 0 ]
do
    content="$(curl -s "$url[0]")"
    echo "$content" | grep "$grepfor"
    delete=($urls[0])
    add=(`echo "$content" | grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*'`)
    urls=( "${urls[@]/$delete}" "{$add[@]}" )
done
```

Comment: Don't correct code in the question.  It invalidates the answers.

Comment: I've figured out my next fuckup, the links I'm adding are relative, i need to prepend urls[0] to the start of each. Also the url is missing a / at the end and I'm not following redirects

Answer (score 2):

Use `"${urls[0]}"` for the first element of the `urls` array, not `$urls[0]`.

To delete the first element of `urls` and to add the `add` array to the end, use

```
urls=( "${urls[@]:1}" "${add[@]}" )
```

Always quote every expansion, even `${#urls[@]}`.

I haven't looked too closely at your curls and greps, but use

```
printf '%s\n' "$content"
```

if you want to be sure that you preserve backslashes in the data.

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement those changes. However even if I change $grepfor to a string which is on the first url I can't get it to grep out that line

Comment: @Shard Well, the `curl` call previous to that line will look for an url ending in `[0]`, so fix that first.  Also `$url` is unset there (it should be `"${urls[0]}"`).

Comment: Ahh thanks that was a big fuck up, I've implemented the changed code into the question. The code is now terminating near immediately. I assume new urls found from the first link aren't correctly being added to $urls